# Como crear un script para activar mi servidor local de node.js y abrir el navegador con esa URL en Windows

Tags: javascript, nodejs, windows, batch

He concluido mi primer proyecto de node.js y ahora quisiera saber cómo a traves de un script `.bat` puedo enceder el servidor usando un comando como este: `node c:\users\user\desktop\project\src\index.js`.
y ademas de eso, que abra el navegador por defecto del sistema y me envie directo a http://localhost:3000/
y también el script quede en segundo plano (la consola de windows no sea visible).

Sé que escribiendo `node c:\users\user\desktop\project\src\index.js` y cambiando la extención del archivo a `.bat` puedo tener el servido encendido. Pero desconozco cómo hacer que abra el navegador, me envie a la URL antes mencionada y hacer que el script se ejecute en segundo plano.
Esto es un proyecto que necesito tenerlo en local y que el cliente pueda abrirlo con un simple doble click.

Adicional a esto: Leí que un modulo de node.js llamado `forever` hace algo similar (o igual). Pero mi equipo no me permite instalar modulos globales

Comment: No veo necesidad de usar un script de comando batch. Pienso que podrías usar [`pm2`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2) para iniciar el servidor como un servicio y luego un acceso directo a la dirección que mencionas, eso abriría el navegador por defecto en la página a la que apuntas. El servicio `pm2` se inicia en segundo plano al iniciar sesión de usario en el equipo, por lo que al momento de hacer doble clic en el acceso directo, ya estará el servidor listo (a menos que realice operaciones muy pesadas durante el arranque). Saludos

Comment: En cuanto a esto: *Pero mi equipo no me permite instalar modulos globales*, eso está bastante mal. No comprendo el porqué no te permite, te da errores o algo?

Comment: Buen día Mauricio... al final logré instalar módulos globales, era una cuestión de Windows (se instalaban pero no los podía ejecutar). Intentaré con lo de ```pm2```

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
@echo off
start /b node "C:\users\user\desktop\project\src\index.js"
timeout /t 5 > nul
start http://localhost:3000/
exit
```

Donde "start /b" lo ejecuta en segundo plano el "timeout /t 5 > nul" te va a dar 5 segundos de retraso para que esperes la ejecución completa del node
y luego abres la web con "start http://localhost:3000/".

Comment: Buen día. Aún queda abierta la consola de Node. Según lo que he leído es algo inevitable. Mi ultima alternativa es usar un Modulo para eso. Muchas gracias por su ayuda